# scss files in Angular are too large

Tags: angular, sass, bundle

I am using 
**ng build --stats-json** 
and then 
**npm run bundle-repor**
 to analyze file bundles in my application used Angular 7.
I got the picture below: [image]

I see .scss files are always much larger than .html and .ts files in each components. They are occupying up to 90% of every component size. I guess that is the reason why my app in production mode are too big.  How can reduce the .scss files ? Thank you!

Comment: one thing I can think of, is perhaps you have an import at the top of each of these scss files? it can be easy to accidentally import more than you intended to with scss imports

Comment: @SnailCoil You are right ! After trying to remove the import, the scss size files are now much much smaller. Thanks a lot !